# belongsTo not working with embedded records?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

If I got some `Color`s, each one with a bunch of `Foo`s (embedded), how do I get back the `color` from any given `foo`?

Given

```
App.ColorSerializer = DS.ActiveModelSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin, {
  attrs: {
    foos: {embedded: 'always'}
  }
});

App.Color = DS.Model.extend({
  color: DS.attr(),
  foos: DS.hasMany('foo')
});

App.Foo = DS.Model.extend({
  color: DS.belongsTo('color'), 
  name: DS.attr()
});
```

The template does NOT print out the right `color` associated to the `foo`:

```
{{#each foo in color.foos}}
  <li>
  {{foo.name}} - {{ foo.color }}
 </li>
{{/each}
```

What am I missing? Is `DS.belongsTo('color')` not the correct way of defining the relationship back? I played with `inverse` and other kinds of embedding too, with no luck.

Please see jsbin: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/1020/edit  (`{{ foo.color }}` prints out nothing)

Answer (score 0):

In order for the `belongsTo` to work on foo, the foo record would have to contain the color id.
For example

```
{
    id:1,
    color: 1,
    name:'something 1'
}
```

Working bin here: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/1024/edit

Comment: This is not very smart of Ember Data. AS USUAL I will have to come up with a workaround... Thanks for your answer, tikotzky.

Answer (score 0):

```
App.Color = DS.Model.extend({
  color: DS.attr(),
  foos: DS.hasMany('foo'),

  didLoad: function() {
    this.get('foos').forEach(function(foo) {
      foo.set('color', this);
    }.bind(this));
  }

});
```

Classy!